# React router v4 cannot display components but no error in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am a noob just started learning React a few days ago. I have a problem while I was working with react router v4.

I have a home page component, like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class AboutPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>About</h1>
                <p>this is the about page</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AboutPage;
```

and here is the App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  Link, Route, Switch,BrowserRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/common/Header';
import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';
import AboutPage from './components/about/AboutPage';



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const home = () =><h1> Home </h1>
    const about = () =><h1> about </h1>

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Header/>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" components={home}/>
          <Route path="/about" components={about}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}



export default App;
```

the headers file is just a nav element I want it for all the component.

The problem is if I click either homepage or about page, it doesn't display the content of these components. It just shows the nav element and that's all.

I built this app using creat-react-app. Is there anything wrong in my code? Thx.

Comment: Reading the docs looks like that the `Route` component is expecting the property `component` and not components. 

I also believe that what you want to render is your `HomePage` and `AboutPage`  component

Comment: you are absolutely right! Can't believe I made such a careless mistake lol.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs looks like that the `Route` component is expecting the property `component` and not components. I also believe that what you want to render is your `HomePage` and `AboutPage` component